# the type {Java_Class}.HashMap is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <String, Integer>

Tags: hashmap, generic-list, parameterized

First time stackoverflow poster, long-time user.
I am attempting to build a project for my Computer Architecture class.  I am using Introduction to Java, text by Y. Daniel Liang.  Trying to build a hashmap / hash table so that I can put items in the table and return a MIPS assembler Immediate / Register / or Jump code.
My problem is that Eclipse is telling me that my HashMap is not generic.
Any ideas about how to fix this error in Eclipse.  Thanks for the help.

Map hashMap = new HashMap();

```
    hashMap.put("add", 1);      //Register codes
    hashMap.put("sub", 1);  
    hashMap.put("addi", 2);     //Immediate codes
```

Comment: It should be warning only no issue.    You can use below to avoid this.                                                                        Map<String,Integer> hashMap = new HashMap<String,Integer>();

Answer (score 0):

I have also gone through the same error but it was resolved just by changing in some properties of project.

Right Click on your project --> Properties --> Select "Java Build Path" from Right hand side panel --> Select "Order and Export" tab --> Click on you JRE System Library or JDK Library --> Click on "Up" button and move it to first position --> Click Ok and clean & build your project.

Do repeat this for all other dependents project as well, if have any dependency.

It resolved my issue because previously the java files were picking other library and packages not from jre package as it was ordered set in last priority.

Thanks,
Shwetank R.